# Find a partition P of R such that |P| = |R| and for each X ∈ P, |X| = |N|.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Find a partition $P$ of $R$ such that $|P| = |R|$ and for each $X \in P, |X| = |N|$.

Approach: partition the set R by each element, so for all $x\in R$ $\bigcup_{x\in R}=R$. The cardinality of each subset is 1 so $|X|=|N|$ and for $|P|=|R|$ I would just use the identity $f(x)=x$

Find a partition $P$ of $R$ such that $|P| = |N|$ and for each $X \in P, |X| = |R|$.

if we arrange each subset like $(0,1],(0,-1],(1,2],(-1,-2]........$ we can easily see that we can count them and by definition $(n,n+1]$ is uncountable

Comment: $|\mathbb{N}| > 1$

Comment: ?>?????????????

Comment: In your case $|X| = 1$ which is not equal to $|\mathbb{N}|$

Comment: What I am saying is that there is a bijection between the natural numbers and each subset

Comment: You can't have a bijection between an infinite set and a finite set.

Comment: Right, I will think about it

Comment: hint????????????

Comment: Is $P:=\{(n,n+1]\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ in your solution? If so then $|P|=|\mathbb N|$ and $|X|=|\mathbb R|$ for each $X\in P$ wich is not the intention.

Comment: that's the second problem XD

Comment: $(0,-1]=\emptyset$. You probably mean $(-1,0]$. Same for $(-1,-2]$.

Comment: @drhab I need help with the first one

Comment: What are the fibers of the map described in my hint? That is: what are the looks of sets like $\{x\in\mathbb R\mid x-\lfloor x\rfloor=0.312\}$?

Comment: it's weird because each set just has one element right?

Comment: No. Note e.g. that $2.312$ and $6.312$ are both elements of the set. And there are more.

Comment: X.Y $x\in Z$ and $Y \in R$ ?????????????????????

Comment: SORRY I meant X.Y X∈Z and Y∈N

Comment: Also try \mathbb{R} and \mathbb{N} and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Preassuming that $N$ stand for the set of natural numbers your approach is wrong (see the comment of @Dark).

Hint: have a look at the function $\mathbb R\to [0,1)$ prescribed by $x\mapsto x-\lfloor x\rfloor$.

---

edit:

Hint for second problem: have a look at functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb Z$ prescribed by $x\mapsto \lfloor x\rfloor$ or $x\mapsto \lceil x\rceil$.

You chose for the second.

(fibers of functions form a partition of their domain)

Comment: I have another similar problem and I think I have the solution. Check my post above

Comment: still confused about the first one

Comment: Realize that for the function prescribed we have: $f^{-1}(\{0.312\})=\{n+0.312\mid n\in\mathbb Z\}$. This set has the cardinality $|\mathbb Z|=|\mathbb N|$. These sets are the elements of the partition.

Comment: so what you are making me do is something like the following  {n}, {n+0.1},{n+0.01},...

Comment: X.Y X∈Z andY∈R ?????????????????????

Comment: That is not what I am making you do. Your last comment doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: sorry I meant   X.Y X∈Z andY∈N

Comment: It still doesn't make sense.Do you agree with my first comment under this question?

Comment: For example if x= 6.325 then f(x)=0.325, if x=5.325 then f(x)=0.325, so basically one set is going to be define as the inputs that satisfy some number in the invertal (0,1)

Comment: Yes, and also if $x=7.325$ or e.g. $476.325$ we have $f(x)=0.325$. Together a countable collection and one of the elements of the partition you are trying to construct. Final solution: $P=\{f^{-1}(\{r\})\mid r\in[0,1)\}$ is the partition. Its elements have the same cardinality as $\mathbb N$ and the cardinality of $P$ is the same as the cardinality of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: you don't feel like |P|=N because we create the sets based on a natural number  {1,325  2,325, 3,325}, so we can name this set 325. How do I show that |P|=|R|

Comment: $|P|=|[0,1)|=|\mathbb R|$

Comment: got it thanks for your patience